With Microsoft switching to Aptos, what happens to the other ClearType fonts?
I've read that Microsoft has decided to change their default Office font — for running text — from Calibri to Aptos:

A change of typeface: Microsoft’s new default font has arrived

But is this the only font that's changing? I know that Calibri is a member of a group: The ClearType Font Collection:

(Calibri)
Cambria
Candara
Consolas
Constantia
Corbel
Meiryo

What's happening to all of them,  as recommended associated/complementing fonts? Is it advised to use another set of fonts which complement Aptos - Or is Aptos supposed to fit in with them?

Note: If you think this question is more appropriate for graphicdesign.stackexchange.com, please comment. I'm not asking whether the change is a good idea, just what Microsoft's typeface plans are.

I'm under the impression that they're changing the default rather than removing fonts, and I'm pretty sure some of the fonts we get bundled with windows date back to 3.11. I'm not confident enough to post an answer, which'd need to be backed up by more than a quick look at a wikipedia page but its reasonably likely old fonts would remain

They will still exist. The only thing changing is the default font. This is definitely out of scope for graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

If the font hasn’t been removed in over a year it won’t be removed without notice and a long lead way.

No announcements have been made regarding any changes to other fonts. Removing fonts is a serious thing and WILL result in document corruption. I don't understand the basis for your question. MS said there's a new font (Aptos) and a change in the default font (setting it to Aptos). They did not say Calibri or the other past defaults are going away or changing.

@music2myear: The basis is, that Calibri and the other fonts are a suite, and supposed to match and complement each other. And the previous change was from TNR-Arial-Courier to Calibri-Cambria-Consolas (basically). Finally, Aptos and Calibri are quite different!

@einpoklum - I will repeat what’s been stated. The default font is changing the old font still exists.

They are not a suite or collection because they compliment each other. They are a collection because they were all designed and optimized for ClearType.

I think you misunderstand ClearType.
ClearType is a suite of fonts related by technology, not design language:

ClearType is a software technology developed by Microsoft that
improves the readability of text on existing LCDs (Liquid Crystal
Displays), such as laptop screens, Pocket PC screens, and flat panel
monitors. With ClearType font technology, the words on your computer
screen look almost as sharp and clear as those printed on a piece of
paper.

These fonts are not primarily designed with the intent of looking good alongside each other or complementing each other, but with the goal of looking good on a specific type of monitor/display.
Aptos looking different means precisely NOTHING regarding the other fonts in this family.

The article you linked says the only change is to the default font.  There is no mention at all of removal of fonts.   It specifically states that the former default fonts, Calibri and Times New Roman, will still be available.
As far as I know, I dont believe any fonts that came with Windows or Office have ever been removed.  Removing these fonts would be an issue for editing/viewing existing documents from any application.  It could also cause issues for the actual applications themselves that are expecting a font to exist for document editing or even the application's GUI.  This is why rarely used fonts like WingDings still exist.  If you include it in an OS or popular office suite, it is going to exist more or less forever.  And that is also the reason, new fonts are rarely introduced into them.
